# Variables explained to a beginner

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, variables

I am having some trouble grasping the concept of variables in TSQL and SQL Server

Here is an example from a stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE schema.procedure
@InvoiceID varchar(28) = ''
@InvoiceGuID varchar(28) = ''
AS

BEGIN
DECLARE @CustomerGuID uniqueidentifier

SELECT @InvoiceGuid = c.InvoiceGuid
FROM customers c
WHERE c.InvoiceID = @InvoiceID

SELECT @CustomerGuID = c.CustomerGuid
FROM customers c
WHERE c.InvoiceGuID = @InvoiceGuID
```

So the parameters are InvoiceID and InvoiceGUID.
If the user only inputs InoviceID, can someone explain to me how the first `SELECT` statement works and then how the second `SELECT` statement works?

1. Is the first one saying, based on the InvoiceID entered by the user, use that to find the InvoiceGuid and populate it for later use?
2. If so, is that InvoiceGuid then able to be used over and over again in the SP with the same value?

Let me know if I need to explain anymore.

Comment: 1) yes 2) yes. Isn't it easier to spend couple of minutes to test your assumptions? And you should tend to use appropriate datatypes. If something is `guid` - let it be a real guid of `uniqueidentifier` type.

Comment: @IvanStarostin you make a valid point, testing my assumptions is a good practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Syntax SQL uses for this has always looked a little odd to me.

```
SELECT @InvoiceGuid = c.InvoiceGuid
FROM customers c
WHERE c.InvoiceID = @InvoiceID
```

effectively this means

```
@InvoiceGuid = (SELECT c.InvoiceGuid
FROM customers c
WHERE c.InvoiceID = @InvoiceID)
```

with `@InvoiceID` using the value passed into the procedure as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little test data for you

```
DECLARE
    @InvoiceID int = null,
    @InvoiceGUID uniqueidentifier = null,
    @CustomerGUID uniqueidentifier = null

    SET @InvoiceID = 1000


    IF OBJECT_ID ('tempdb..#Invoices') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Invoices

    CREATE TABLE #Invoices(
        InvoiceID varchar(28),
        InvoiceGUID uniqueidentifier,
        CustomerGUID uniqueidentifier)

    declare @ct int = 0

    WHILE @ct < 5
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO #Invoices (InvoiceID, InvoiceGUID, CustomerGUID)
        SELECT 
            1000 + @ct as InvoiceID,
            NEWID() as InvoiceGUID,
            NEWID() as CustomerGUID
        SET @ct = @ct + 1
    END

    --Check your data to see what we filled
    SELECT * From #Invoices


    --Here we are setting the variable @InvoiceGUID to the GUID for the Invoice which you passed in via @InvoiceID. 
    --It will overwrite anything that is in the @InvoiceGUID, for example, if you passed something in.
    SELECT 
        @InvoiceGUID = InvoiceGUID
    FROM 
        #Invoices
    WHERE
        InvoiceID = @InvoiceID

    --Check to make sure we got the variable. Also compare this to the table. It should be the same.
    SELECT @InvoiceGUID as InvoiceGUIDparameter



    --Now set the @CustomerGUID based off the @InvoiceGUID we just selected. 
    SELECT 
        @CustomerGUID = CustomerGUID
    FROM 
        #Invoices
    WHERE
        InvoiceGUID = @InvoiceGUID


    --Check the value to compare
    SELECT @CustomerGUID as CustomerGUIDparameter


    --The only catch here is TSQL batches. Your parameters won't be "global" so to speak if you have mutlple batch statements.
    --https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175502(v=sql.105).aspx
    --https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms712553(v=vs.85).aspx
```

Comment: Thank you, I will test this out!

Comment: Be sure to let us know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

The first `select` uses the given `@InvoiceID` to assign a value to `@InvoiceGuid` and that value overwrites any value passed in to `@InvoiceGuid` when calling the stored procedure.

If you are trying to create a single procedure to accept either `@InvoiceID` or `@InvoiceGuID`, you can check the values to see which is an empty string and make the appropriate select.